# Populate a table with random set of rows from another table on insert using a trigger

Tags: mysql, select, triggers, insert

I got this problem.
I have a mysql database with this tables:

```
USERS(Cod,Interests)
SURVEY(Cod,Target_Interests)
USERS_OF_A_SURVEY(CodSurvey,CodUser)
```

with **Interests** having the same set of values of **Target_Interests**.

I would like having a trigger in my database that, after an `insert` on **SURVEY**,puts 1000 entries on `USERS_OF_A_SURVEY` in this way:

for example: i put into SURVEY the value **`SURV001,MUSIC`**.

Now the trigger should put 1000 entries on `USERS_OF_A_SURVEY` with **CodSurvey** fixed at `SURV001`, and `CodUser` randomly from the users with `Interests = MUSIC`.

Don't know if I explained my problem properly, I hope yes. HELP ME!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_survey_after_insert
AFTER INSERT ON survey
FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO users_of_a_survey (codsurvey, coduser)
  SELECT NEW.cod, cod
    FROM users
   WHERE interests = NEW.target_interests
   ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 1000
;
```

Insert a few rows

```
INSERT INTO survey VALUES('SURV001', 'music');
INSERT INTO survey VALUES('SURV002', 'music');
```

Content of `users_of_a_survey` after insert

```
| CODSURVEY | CODUSER |
-----------------------
|   SURV001 |       3 |
|   SURV001 |       1 |
 .....................
|   SURV002 |       1 |
|   SURV002 |       4 |
......................
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6c3f/1)** demo.

**UPDATE**:

> And if i would like to do the inverse? Delete all users from
>   "users_of_a_survey" when I delete their survey?

You can either go with a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger or with [`FOREIGN KEY ... ON DELETE CASCADE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

A trigger may look like

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_survey_after_delete
BEFORE DELETE ON survey
FOR EACH ROW 
  DELETE FROM users_of_a_survey 
   WHERE codsurvey = OLD.cod
;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af17d/1)** demo.

Comment: And if i would like to do the inverse? Delete all users from "users_of_a_survey" when I delete their survey? EXAMPLE: i delete SURV1 and i want to delete all the entries of "users_of_a_survey" with CodSurvey = SURV1

Comment: @FrancescoTronca See updated answer. You may consider to up vote :)